# How to remove iPhone 5 compatibility from Xcode project?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, iphone-5

Accidentally I allowed Xcode to add the iPhone 5 launch image for a massive app project where I don't want to adapt to iPhone 5 just yet.

I deleted the launch image but the simulator keeps launching it in enlarged iPhone 5 mode. I couldn't find a key in infoplist either. How can I completely remove iPhone 5 support?

Comment: Does the application have black bars on the top and bottom when you are using the iPhone 5 simulator?

Comment: No, the application is shifted all the way up and there is a giant gap at the bottom. It is in iPhone 5 support mode even though I deleted the iPhone 5 launch image.

Answer (score 6):

The following worked for me.

- Remove the file from Xcode.
- Delete the file from your Finder folder.
- Empty the trash.
- Clean your Xcode project.
- Delete App from device and simulator.

Comment: I was struggling for past two hours..  your solution workd.. thanks...:)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you delete Default-568h@2x.png from your project then it will remove the iPhone 5 full screen features.

Comment: No it will not, as stated in my question.

Answer (score -1):

Remove armv7s in Build Setting Architecture and remove the Retina 4Inch Image in Summary of your Target Clean Build. Then Your Application will start support for 3.5 Inch screen only